# Excel Macros - Insert Rows above specific text to separate out by page

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help.

I have an output from a very old system which gives us trucking manifests. Think of them like shipping slips.

Each one starts with the Title "       Manifest Number: #####     " Where #### is the actual number.

The catch is that when these get printed, they need to be spaced out so it's one per page. (which is never the case in the raw output.) Page one always has the first manifest (ok) but also, the second manifest. I find myself, daily, counting the spaces and inserting rows above the second manifest title until it is on the second page. Then I count the rows between the 2nd and 3rd and insert spaces above the third title until it is on page 3 and so on. When doing 18 pages, this gets tedious.

I'm looking to see if you can help me with a macro that searches out the title "*MANIFEST NUMBER*"  then, counts the rows before the next page break (page breaks are every 47 lines) and inserts that number of rows above. Then perform that action again for the next one.

I can provide an example file if needed.

EDIT: I have solved my problem. Please see below for the code that I used.

```
Sub ManifestSplit()
'
' ManifestSplit Macro

Dim gap As Long
gap = 7

Dim searchText As String
searchText = "*MANIFEST NUMBER*"

Dim originalRange As Range
Set originalRange = Range("A" & (gap + 1) & ":A1000")

Dim manifestTotal As Long
manifestTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(originalRange, searchText)

MsgBox ("The total number of Manifests is " & manifestTotal + 1)

Dim manifestLocation As Long
Dim numberofrowstoPage
Dim newRange As Range

Dim counter As Long

If manifestTotal = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("There is only one Manifest. Macro will end.")
Else
    For counter = 1 To manifestTotal
           Set newRange = Range("A" & (gap + 1) & ":A1000")
           manifestLocation = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(searchText, newRange, 0) + gap
'              MsgBox ("The " & counter & " manifest is on line " & manifestLocation)

           numberofrowstoPage = counter * 47 - manifestLocation
'              MsgBox ("The Number of Rows that will be inserted is " & numberofrowstoPage)

           Rows(manifestLocation & ":" & (manifestLocation + numberofrowstoPage + 1)).Insert Shift:=xlDown

           gap = 47 * counter + 2

    Next counter
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You should put up a sample code or at least make an effort first. If you google "how to have macro search for text" you can probably find the first answer. Then google "macro to count spaces" or "how to count spaces in excel" and you'll be on your way.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to set a page break?

Comment: @PGCodeRider I was working on it on the side. I didn't post it because I didn't want to swing people to use my janky code over a clean solution. However, I did solve and have since edited the OP with my solve.

Answer (score 0):

No need to insert an arbitrary number of rows; just set a page beak.

```
Sub makeReadyForPrinting()
    Dim r As Long, fr As Long
    With Worksheets("sheet6")
        .ResetAllPageBreaks
        With .Columns(1).Cells
            fr = .Find(What:="Manifest Number:*", After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlNext, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
            r = .FindNext(After:=.Cells(fr)).Row
            Do While fr <> r
                .Parent.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=.Cells(r)
                r = .FindNext(After:=.Cells(r)).Row
            Loop
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

The example in your narrative included a leading space in `" Manifest Number: ##### "`. I've assumed that was a typo and removed it.